# PHP.INI & session.save_path & ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-elasticache

Below is from http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php#ini.memcache.hash-strategy

> session.save_path string Defines a comma separated of server urls to
>   use for session storage, for example "tcp://host1:11211,
>   tcp://host2:11211".

**Question:**
AWS ElastiCache gives you node endpoints and a configuration endpoint (which I believe is a DNS CNAME to the ElastiCache Cluster).

If I put the configuration endpoint value into `session.save_path` will this mean Sessions use the Cluster rather then a specific node and therefore always use an active node?

I understand if a node is rebooted/removed the data held will be lost and therefore sessions on that node will be lost.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not work that way. You need to use the Amazon memcached client that has support for Auto Discovery.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoDiscovery.html